# Angular: How can I request the images as needed to accelerate the load (using ngx-bootstrap)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, performance, ngx-bootstrap

I am making a request to a personal API that returns the url of about **300** images (approximately) and all these images I must show them in a Carousel.

The problem is that my page lasts a long time to load because when the surcharge begins to load the 300 images. the carousel shows 6 images per pass, and what I want is for you to load the images as you click on the "NEXT" or "PREV" button to make the page load faster. That would be the right way to do it, right?

I'm starting with angular and it's the first time I make an application of this type. Somebody could help me? I have researched but I have not found much information that helps me or I do not know the terminology of what I need to use in this case.

This is the **code of the carousel** where I show the images that I comment, I am using NGX-BOOTSTRAP:

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div> <span class="text-hot">
          <b>HOT</b> </span> </div>
      </div>
      <div id="div-redondo" class="d-flex ml-2 align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="text-hot align-middle">
              list
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Imagen de Pre-Carga-->
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center" id="cont-preCarga" *ngIf="preCarga">
    <img src="../../assets/images/slider/spinner.gif">
</div>

<app-modal  [inmueble]="this.inmueble2" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal> 


<carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide"
          [singleSlideOffset]="singleSlideOffset"
          [interval]="false"
          [noWrap]="noWrap">
  <slide class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let imagenPortada of this.hostlistService.inmuebles; let index=index" style="width: 500px;">
    <img src="{{url}}{{imagenPortada.id}}_{{imagenPortada.fotos[0]}}" alt="imagen de slide" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 300px;">   <!-- <-----HERE IS WHERE I AM SHOWING THE IMAGES -->
    <!--<img src="../../assets/images/slider/logo.png" alt="imagen de slide" style="z-index: 10; width: 100%; height: 300px; position: absolute; left: 0; top:0;">-->
    <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
    </div> -->
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">  
        <p class="text-left text-precio"> <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign">
          </i> Precio: {{imagenPortada.precio | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2'}} 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">  
        <p class="text-left"> <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Ubicacion: {{imagenPortada.precio | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2'}} 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex col-12">
        <div class="cont-verDetalles d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button (click)="obtenerInfo(imagenPortada)" type="button" class="mt-2 btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">Ver detalles</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

This is an **image of the carousel**, where I only show 6 images, when I click on the "NEXT" or "PREV" button they run one by one to show the following:

[image: carousel]

And here you can see what I want to avoid, that they are loading the pile of images that I do not need to show until I need them in the carousel since they are too many:

[image: images]

How could I do to avoid that?

I would be very grateful to the person who can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. To start off, we'll have 2 arrays

- a `masterArray` which has all the URLs of the images;
- an `imagesArray` which will be array linked to the carousel, it will have only 1 image to start of with... which means that when the page loads, we had loaded only one image.
- we simply add a url from the `masterArray` into the `imagesArray` on each slide change event [name of the event is: `activeSlideChange`];

relevant **HTML** (single slide carousel):

```
<carousel (activeSlideChange)='gotChange()'>
  <slide *ngFor="let img of imagesArray; let idx of index"  >
    <img src="{{img}}" alt="slide {{idx}}" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

relevant **TS** (single slide carousel):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CarouselComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(CarouselComponent) myCarousel: CarouselComponent;
  name = 'Angular';
  masterArray = ['https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/1.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/2.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/3.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/4.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/5.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/6.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/7.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/8.jpg',
  ];
  imagesArray = ['https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/1.jpg'];
  loopcomplete: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  gotChange() {
    console.log('got change', this.myCarousel.activeSlide);
    if (!this.loopcomplete) {
      if (this.myCarousel.activeSlide + 1 < this.masterArray.length) {
        this.imagesArray.push(this.masterArray[this.myCarousel.activeSlide + 1]);
      } else { this.loopcomplete = true; }
    }
  }

}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnxdh1)

the image to show the lazy loading of images
[image]

**UPDATE**: in light of questioner's comment below... the event that we're looking for is `slideRangeChange`

relevant **HTML** (multi slide carousel):

```
<carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide"
          [singleSlideOffset]="singleSlideOffset"
          [noWrap]="noWrap"
          (activeSlideChange)='gotChange()'
          (slideRangeChange)='gotRangeChange()'
          [showIndicators]='false'
          [interval]='false'
           >
  <slide *ngFor="let img of imagesArray; let idx of index"  >
    <img [src]="img" alt="slide {{idx}}" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

relevant **TS** (multi slide carousel):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CarouselComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(CarouselComponent) myCarousel: CarouselComponent;
  name = 'Angular';
  masterArray = ['https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/1.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/2.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/3.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/4.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/5.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/6.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/7.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/8.jpg',
  ];
  imagesArray = ['https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/1.jpg',
    'https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/assets/images/nature/2.jpg',
  ];
  loopcomplete: boolean = false;
  itemsPerSlide = 2;
  singleSlideOffset = true;
  noWrap = true;
  activeRange = 0;

  constructor() { }

  gotRangeChange() {
    if (!this.loopcomplete) {

      if (this.activeRange + 2 < this.masterArray.length) {
        this.activeRange = this.activeRange + 2;
        this.imagesArray = this.imagesArray.concat(this.masterArray[this.activeRange]);
        this.imagesArray = this.imagesArray.concat(this.masterArray[this.activeRange + 1]);
      } else {
        this.loopcomplete = true;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz (multi slide carousel)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqs2k6)

Comment: Hi friend. First of all thank you very much for taking the time to respond. I do not understand much the code, I see that you have a method that is activated in the carousel (I think it is every time you change the image automatically), but I do not understand how you do so that the request is made only when the image needed. if you look at my code I have something similar to what you have, except that I do not have the method (activeSlideChange) = 'gotChange ()', could you explain me a little?

Comment: Whenever a slide is changed (whether through the user clicking on the arrow icons or the slide changing automatically)... the default activeSlideChange method will be fired... at this point we need an image but don't have any image in the 'imagesArray'... so, we just insert an image from our `masterArray` into our `imagesArray` so that the carousel has the next image which it needs

Comment: I get it. and how could I apply it to my code? I tried it but being a multilist, everything went complicated.

Comment: friend excuse the audacity. Would there be any way to make another quick consultation in private? this is my mail just in case it does not bother you: julian21931500@gmail.com

Comment: are you there friend?

Comment: @JulianProg, I updated the answer with multiple images as per your request... Does that work for you?

Comment: I think so.  I'm going to try it  you know that I have a carousel and a button "see details", when you click, a modal opens that has another carousel.  the problem is that when in this carousel I change the images (for example up to image 3), then I close and open another modal, this carousel starts from image 3, how could it be so that it always starts from image 1?

Comment: could you help me with that?  and excuse the audacity.

Comment: HI @JulianProg, This question and answer have been too long already... how about you accept this answer, so that it is closed... and raise another question with demo code for your multi-carousel with modals scenario - else this will be too difficult for anyone else to follow (I say this because as we ask questions, a global knowledge base is being built which we gotta protect and keep simple)... I hope you understand... do share the link of the next question here so that i can address that - cheers

Comment: Hi. Here I have my question raised. could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874288/how-to-make-a-ngfor-always-start-from-the-first-position-in-angular/56886883#56886883